# Article not indexed by Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar, indexing

I have a paper published on a good journal, but after more than 2 months it is still not indexed by Google Scholar.

All other papers from the same volume (november) can be found in GS, just my single paper is left out for some reason. The same paper also appears as a preprint on arXiv, but not even this version is found within GS.
Is there anything I can do? I tried to add it manually, but I can just list the title and authors, I cannot add a link, the DOI or force GS to index the paper.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP11(2021)011

Comment: [This paper on google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1574311527775398860&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33)?

Comment: @CJR That paper has a different last author and misses the word 'holographic' in the title. I guess Google Scholar finds the two papers so similar it gets confused, compare https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00519 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.05343 Searching scholar for links to the first article or its DOI seems to just bring the results listed under your link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my published article seemingly not indexed by Google or Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88412/why-is-my-published-article-seemingly-not-indexed-by-google-or-google-scholar)

Comment: @Sursula not really: there the problem was the Journal, but I'm 100% sure that the Journal is fine in my case (all other papers from the same Journal are listed in GS).
I agree with Anyon, probably the fact that the two papers have very similar name confuses GS.